# Как выделить 2 последних символа при неопределённом x?

Tags: python

Предположим есть выражение "x12" в котором x может иметь любую длину. Нужно отсечь x чтобы осталось только 12.

Comment: `str = 'asdfgh12' print(str[-2:])` - вернет 2 последних символа в строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В python это называется [срез](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html)

**string[from:to]**

```
str = 'asdfgh12' 
print(str[-2:])
```

Таким образом, мы можем получить 2 последних символа строки.